# Solving the recurrence relation $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + n$

Tags: proof-techniques, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, landau-notation, induction

Solving the recurrence relation $T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + n$.
The book from which this example is, falsely claims that $T(n) = O(n)$ by guessing $T(n) \leq cn$ and then arguing

$\qquad \begin{align*} T(n) & \leq 2(c \lfloor n/2 \rfloor ) + n \\ &\leq cn +n \\ &=O(n) \quad \quad \quad \longleftarrow \text{ wrong!!} \end{align*}$

since $c$ is constant.The error is that we have not proved the *exact* form of the inductive hypothesis.

Above I have exactly quoted what the book says. Now my question is why cannot we write $cn+n=dn$ where $d=c+1$ and now we have $T(n) \leq dn$ and hence $T(n) = O(n)$?

Note:

1. The correct answer is $T(n) =O(n \log n).$
2. The book I am referring here is *Introduction to algorithms* by Cormen et al., page 86, 3rd edition.

Comment: No you can't. Your induction hypothesis is $T(n)\le cn$, and **this** is what you have to prove. Actually, the recurrence does not solve to $O(n)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The authors give the answer:

> The error is that we have not proved the *exact form* of the inductive hypothesis, that is, that $T(n) \leq cn$.

Granted, that is hard to understand if you are not used to do inductions (right), because they do not do the induction explicitly/rigorously. In short: you need to have *one* constant $c$ for all $n$, but this (un)proof constructs many (one per $n$).

---

In long, remember what $T(n) \in O(n)$ means:

$\qquad \displaystyle \exists c \in \mathbb{N}.\, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}.\, \forall n \geq n_0.\, T(n) \leq cn$

or, equivalently,

$\qquad \displaystyle \exists c \in \mathbb{N}.\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} T(n) \leq cn$.

The second form works better for an induction as you know the anchor. So you need *one* constant $c$ that provides an upper bound for *all* $n$.

Let's inspect what the induction does:

- Induction anchor: The anchor of $T$ is not explicitly given, but it's constant, so we find a suitable $c$.
- Induction hypothesis: There is some $c$ so that $T(k) \leq cn$ for all $k\leq n$, for some arbitrary but fixed  $n$.
- Inductive step: as shown in the question, construct $d > c$ so that $T(n+1) \leq dn$.

So, in effect, we construct a *new* constant for every $n$. That does not fit the definition of $O$ at all! And, worse, it is completely meaningless: *every* function can be "bounded" by *any other* function if you can adjust the factor with $n$.

Regarding the induction proof, $c$ has to be part of the claim (and it is, hidden in the $O$), that is bound "outside" of the induction. Then, the same $c$ shows up in anchor, hypothesis and step. See the last part of [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2799/98) for an example.

Comment: Thanks , I understood the point and ofcourse it is meaningless to have new constant for every $n$.
But how you had written " or equivalently ...."(third statment) i.e. can we always find such $c$ for which $n_0$ is $1$.

Comment: In practice, $c = 10^{10^{100!}}$ usually works.

Comment: @SaurabhHota: Given $n_0$ and $c$ from the first form, $c + \max_{n \leq n_0} T(n)/n$ works as constant for the second form. The other direction is immediate, i.e. the constant carries over with $n_0=1$ (or an arbitrary value, in fact).